# Email attachment appears in email body as plain text in Laravel 4.2 rather than attached to email

Tags: laravel, email-attachments

I am trying to send a .gz file attached to an email (via beanstalkd queue) of a database backup. The email is sending but the file is just in the body of the email as plain text.

Here is a sample of the email body:

```
--_=_swift_v4_1423559861_751dd26786296c2c903217a32b0dcd8e_=_ Content-Type: application/x-gzip; name=2015-02-09_sign_dev.sql.gz Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=2015-02-09_sign_dev.sql.gz H4sIAEPM2VQAA9RaW3faypJ+nv0rNE9OzjiZvqh18aystW0jMMQSMUgC9EJa3S1zkYAYEWN+/ZSE (cont)
```

I have tried looking around on google and there are a few mentions of this issue from two months ago but no solutions. The closest *solution* is a [mention of this issue on github](http://laravel.io/forum/11-25-2014-all-emails-with-an-attachment-shows-as-plain-text-since-last-composer-update) but the owner has said the commit was reverted once this issue was discovered.

All my packages are up-to-date. I have tried many variations of sending the email including not sending via the queue but always the same issue.

the relevant script is:

```
Mail::queue('emails.db-backup', [], function ($message) use ($fullBackupPath, $backupFileName)
    {
        $message->to(Config::get('mail.backups.address'), Config::get('mail.backups.name'))
            ->subject('DB Backup')
            ->attach($fullBackupPath);
    });
```

The view is actually blank at the moment so all that should be coming though is an email with an attachment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some fresh eyes and a nights sleep and I have resolved this issue. Adding text into the email view seemed to solve the problem; a simple yet effective solution.